# VScode extensions: CODE RUNNER and PYTHON PREVIEWER do not use the interpreter I select

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm using some VSCODE extensions that I find really interesting, those are: `Python Preview` (https://github.com/dongli0x00/python-preview), and `Code Runner` (https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner.git).

I normally let VScode select the environment for python development and it is so good, it always chooses the right one:
[image]

So the Problem here is, that, as you can see, in the code I'm using `MatPlotLib` and `NumPy` modules.  And when I use either `Python Preview` or `Code Runner`, they do not detect the right interpreter, I don't know if they follow the interpreter that VScode selects automatically or if some configuration is needed in order for them to do it.

These are the captures of both extensions selecting the wrong interpreter:

PYTHON PREVIEW:
[image: PYTHON_PREVIEWER image]

CODE RUNNER:
[image: CODERUNNER image]

Well I'd just like to know if this happens due to the extensions configuration and if I can solve it somehow :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Code Runner allows you to point to an interpreter as follows:

1. Search Settings for “executor map” and click “edit in settings.json”
2. Paste in this line:

   ```json
   "python": "$pythonPath -u $fullFileName",
   ```

   So that the entire file looks like this:

   ```json
   {
       ...
       "code-runner.executorMap": {
           "python": "$pythonPath -u $fullFileName",
       }
       ...
   }
   ```

This way Code Runner uses the interpreter you have set in “Python Path”. (Search that in your settings.)

The [Code Runner README](https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner#configuration) contains other variables you may use in `code-runner.executorMap`, in case your Python executable is located someplace else.

PS You might also want to add interpreters for other languages, if you use any.

Comment: Special thanks to you, it worked pretty straight forward and as expected.  Little question: what is the `$` symbol used for in those settings json files?

Comment: And what are those `fullFileName` and `pythonPath`?  Are they kind of VSCode variables? (because I know that `pythonPath` should be the python path that is selected but idk how do they work in those json files)

Comment: @DanielCorrea I think they are Code Runner-specific, because if I Google for “VSCode $fullFileName” I only find Code Runner-related articles

Comment: Thanks dude, it was really helpful to me :)

Answer (score 0):

> This is not a fix, but a workaround.

I had the same issue as you have.
I tried many methods mentioned in variour blogs as well as stackoverflow, but it seems it wont fix the issue.

Then I removed Python2 completely from my system, as I don't use Py2 for anything, to make it working.

```
I recommend you to remove Python2 if you dont use that.
```

This will fix your issue

> Tried and Tested

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and post your answer

Comment: I'm on windows so I don't have py2 installed. But thanks

Comment: Oh, sorry for that, 
Then you may have installed module on global scale, outside of ur venv. (I had this issue too.) I created venv using pycharm, and if i dont check "inherit global packages", then I need to install the modules, again on the venv. Hope this helps.

Comment: No dude, I wish the problem were that easy.  I'm sure I have the modules installed on the venv just because I never install packages globally and I've checked those modules in the terminal (checking inside and outside the venv), I know they're not installed globally but in the venv.

Answer (score 0):

I created a virtual environment and when i clicked the option **Python: Run Current File in Python Interactive Window**, the environment was activated automatically like the following screenshot shows:

[image]

However, pressing `Ctrl+Shift+P` to open the panel and select the option: **Terminal: Create New Integrated Terminal** is used more often to activate the virtual environment.

So check if you can get the above output which means you activate the virtual env successfully by pressing **Ctrl+Shift+`**, which is the shortcut key of creating new integrated terminal. If the environment is still not activated, press **Ctrl+,** to open settings.json and add

> **"python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true**

Reference: [python environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments). Try this and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: that is not the problem I have, my vscode terminal is working fine and when I click the option `Python: Run Current File in Python Interactive Window` it activates the environment correctly.   My real problem is with `CODE RUNNER` extension, that shows the output of a code in the OUTPUT panel, not the terminal panel.

Comment: press ctrl+, to open settings.json and add an entry for python.pythonPath manually inside your Workspace Settings. the value of python.pythonpath is the path of currently used interptrter. try this and reload window to see if this problem goes away

Comment: I don't wanna mess my python interpreter path, as I told you, I don't think the problem is from vscode specifically but from the extensions, my interpreter is being right chosen by vscode, I think the problem is from the extensions and I thought maybe there was a way of accessing extensions settings and changing the path of the extension, not the path of global python for vscode (bc that one is working perfectly).  But thanks.

Comment: From my opinion, if you haven't change the default settings, first , you should check the environment, so what i said before just want to make sure the current project is using the right python.exe. you thought that's the mistake of code runner, then you should  go to look code runner features in extension marketplace for further information. have you tried to add "code-runner.cwd": "path/to/working/directory" in your settings.json to manually set the path of code runner current working directory?

Comment: Well it happens a weird thing: I added "code-runner.cwd": "path/to/working/directory" to settings.json in the folder i'm working in.  But now when i run the code with the extension (ctrl+alt+N), it starts running but never ends, it says `[RUNNING]` so I know it started, but it does not show anything and ever finishes, I don't know what is wrong with this extension dude.

Comment: I got the same problem. Delete the setting code-runner.cwd  and restart vscode, output will show there. If it still doesn't work, It's recommended that you delete and reinstall code-runner.

Comment: I tried man, but it still doesn't work, thanks a lot for trying to help :) there's just something bad with this thing.